# Search/replacing multiple lines using VI

Tags: ubuntu, vi

I'm trying to edit a file on Ubuntu using VI so I can search/replace using two lines. The lines are often on different lines for each file (So i can't use the search by line) and the text i'm looking for is

```
[wan2]
#disable = yes
```

They are always one after each other and i'm looking to change it from the above to the below

```
    [wan2]
disable = yes
```

I've tried a few different ways around this but I keep getting the below:

```
E486: Pattern not found: [wan2]\n#disable = yes
```

Below and a few slight alterations is about as close as I came, I hope this is something stupid I can fix but i'm slightly stumped.

```
:s/[wan2]\n#disable = yes /[wan2] \ndisable = yes
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Ex command

The most reliable way is to use the Ex command:

```
:/wan2/+1s/^#//
```

This runs `s/^#//` on the line following the occurrence of the string `wan2`
indicated by `/wan2/+1`.  As an Ex command this has the advantage of working in all Vi implementations (not just Vim).

---

#### Vim substitution

Your Vim substitution command didn’t have the square brackets escaped so the `[wan2]` part regex would be interpreted as a character collections for matching. Also, the trailing space after “yes” may have prevented a match. The following should also work for you in Vim:

```
:s/\[wan2\]\n#disable = yes/[wan2]\rdisable = yes/
```